# Trouble installing flask-socketio

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, pip, flask-socketio

I'm trying to install Flask-socketIO using pip  :

```
 pip install flask-socketIO
```

But in the end I'm facing this error :

```
   cc -O2 -fPIC -Wimplicit -DLIBEV_EMBED=1 -DEV_COMMON= -DEV_CLEANUP_ENABLE=0 -DEV_EMBED_ENABLE=0 -DEV_PERIODIC_ENABLE=0 -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libev -Ilibev -I/home/abhishek/.virtualenvs/test/include -c gevent/gevent.core.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent/gevent.core.o
    gevent/gevent.core.c:9:22: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
     #include "pyconfig.h"
                          ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/abhishek/.virtualenvs/test/bin/pypy -c "import setuptools,
```

Comment: Did you ever fix this error?

Comment: there is some problem if you install flask-socketIO after you have installed pypy interpreter.
So the best bet would be setup a virtaulenv and then install socket-io.
Later install pypy interpreter.
If any error , you can always set a new virtual env.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to have the Python Development package installed.

On CentOS / RHEL:

```
yum install python-devel
yum install python-lxml
```

On Ubuntu / Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
```

Comment: Still facing the error :
Command "/home/abhishek/.virtualenvs/test/bin/pypy -c "import ..."
Ever since I have installed pypy I have seen pip throwing errors installing libraries

Comment: What's the rest of the stack trace above that error line?

Comment: Same here, Have issued this command and flask isn't found anymore on Ubuntu.